# How to set up unique behaviours with Scriptable Objects (Skills/ability system)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a complex Skill/Ability system on Unity, that may have some conditions to trigger unique behaviours, and other things. For example, I have a skill called Shatter, that does damage and have some conditions: If the enemy is currently bleeding, applies Armor Break. If the enemy armor is broke, applies Bleeding. If affected by both, apply more stacks of Bleeding. That's just an example of which type of behaviour/conditions i wish my skills to have.

I already created one and made it work with bunchs of prefabs, instantiation and monobehaviour/inheritance chaos, but it showed me some problems that I wasn't able to solve, so now I'm giving a try to Scriptable Objects and I decided to rewrite the game for now.

This is what I used to make Shatter (inherits from WarriorSkill, that inherits from Skill) works with monobehaviour/inheritance (Conditions are just debuffs in this example):

```
public class Shatter : WarriorSkill, IConditionable
{
    public GameObject armorBreakCondition, bleedingCondition, hemorrhageCondition, coagulationCondition;

    [SerializeField] double damage;

    public double Damage { get { return damage; } private set { damage = value;}

    public override void OnActivate()
    {
        base.OnActivate();
        target.TakeDamage(Damage);

        bool bleeding = false;
        bool armorBreak = false;

        foreach(Transform condition in target.conditionsPanel.transform)
        {
            if (condition.GetComponent<Condition>().GetType() == typeof(Bleeding))
                bleeding = true;

            if (condition.GetComponent<Condition>().GetType() == typeof(CArmorBreak))
                armorBreak = true;
        }

        if(bleeding && armorBreak)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<Bleeding>().AddStacks(4);
        }
        else if(armorBreak)
        {
            OnCondition(bleedingCondition);
        }
        else if(bleeding)
        {
            OnCondition2(armorBreakCondition);
        }
    }

    private void OnCondition(GameObject condition)
    {
        condition.GetComponent<Bleeding>().hemorrhageCondition = hemorrhageCondition;
        condition.GetComponent<Bleeding>().coagulationCondition = coagulationCondition;
        target.AddCondition(condition);
    }

    private void OnCondition2(GameObject condition)
    {
        condition.GetComponent<CArmorBreak>().armorBreak = 0.25f;
        condition.GetComponent<CArmorBreak>().duration = 50;
        target.AddCondition(condition);
    }
}
```

With that, I needed to adapt to some prefab instantiation/serialization limitations, like, I wasn't able to just drag n' drop the hemorrhage and coagulation prefabs to the Bleeding prefab, because when I instantiate it, it shows Empty. Those "bad solutions" I've got didn't make me satisfied, and more problems were showing up as I write the code. So, now I'm trying to fix and improve my code with scriptable objects. It's important to note that every skill has some really special features/conditions and unique behaviours like that Shatter ability. I may describe more examples if necessary.

Comment: To me this sounds like the use case for [enum](https://www.studica.com/blog/unity-tutorial-how-to-use-enums) like `public enum HealthState{ default, bleeding, armorBrake, armorBrakeAndBleeding, ... }`

Comment: The problem is, it has lots of conditions: poison, disease, stun, hemorrhage, even good ones, like coagulation, power ups, and embrace all the possibilities and combinations between these conditions in a enum is pretty much impossible/inviable from this point of view

Comment: Oh ok well than I guess bools fit better. enums are better if some of them don't "overlap" but only one is possible at the same time

Comment: Probably too late but if enums would really suffice, then you could use flagged enums, so it could mix up values really easy. Like Enum.ArmorBreak | Enum.Bleeding would have both. You could check like this: value & (Enum.ArmorBreak | Enum.Bleeding) != 0 or = 0 for contains or not contains.

Comment: Also, how did you end up designing your skill system? I'm trying to design something like it where behaviors/effect are decoupled from the skill itself and also easily used with different animations/characters.